# Is there anyway to import a publish profile directly into Team Services Build Definition for .NET Core

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, .net-core, azure-devops, entity-framework-migrations

I have a .NET Core application that I have configured Continuous Integration with through the Azure deployment wizard.

[image]

This process created a build definition inside of my team services that I have configured to build and deploy on check in of source code.

[image]

The code builds and deploys successfully but I am having trouble getting database changes through migrations to be executed as part of CI. I have downloaded the publish profile from Azure for the web application and imported it into Visual Studio. I could then edit the publish setting to include running migrations on publish as you can see below.

[image]

When I run this manually from Visual Studio it publishes successfully and also executes the migration script.

So I am wondering is there a way to import this edited and working publish profile into my Team Services Continuous Integration?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Visual Studio Build step with arguments of `/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile="[your publish profile]"` instead.

1. Modify publish profile file to add Password and AllowUntrustedCertificate nodes. (refer to: [Publish an Azure Web Site from the Command Line](https://greatrexpectations.com/2013/02/02/publish-an-azure-web-site-from-the-command-line/))
2. Add `/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile="[your publish profile]"` arguments to Visual Studio Build task.